# 2to3 not resolving .sort() to sorted()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2to3

I'm attempting to convert a library from Py 2.7.x to Py 3.7.x using 2to3 on Win10.  Following reference from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html).

I've seen that to convert some parts of Python you need to explicitly add Fixers, specifically:

> **idioms**
>
> This optional fixer performs several transformations that make
> Python code more idiomatic. Type comparisons like type(x) is SomeClass
> and type(x) == SomeClass are converted to isinstance(x, SomeClass).
> while 1 becomes while True. This fixer also tries to make use of
> sorted() in appropriate places. For example, this block
>
> L = list(some_iterable) L.sort() is changed to
>
> L = sorted(some_iterable)

So I add it to my commandline:

```
2to3 --output-dir=C:\my\py3\module -f all -f buffer -f idioms -f set_literal -f ws_comma -W -n C:\my\py2\module
```

2to3 will generate the correct files in the C:\my\py3\module folder but list.sort() has not been resolved to sorted(list)

What am I missing here?

Comment: `list.sort()` is still a thing - it sorts the list in place. `sorted(..)` creates a new sorted list and returns it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product of trying to convert a lib off github at 3am.  The real issue is the changes between the return value of dictionary .keys() between Py2 and Py3.

Snippet from lib I was running through 2to3:

```
keys = timeSamples.keys()
keys.sort()
```

Which I changed to:

```
keys = sorted(timeSamples.keys())
```

If I'd actually read the error message would have seen was trying to call .sort() on dict_keys type not list in Py3.

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d16f6176abdecbb7ab231dc78beccfaa095beff6/Lib/lib2to3/fixes/fix_idioms.py#L47-L64) the fixer literally only works for an

```
x = list(z)
x.sort()
```

pattern, not anything fancier. After all 2to3 doesn't do type analysis.